# How to get SMS 2FA verification on PC using Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, thinkpad, mobile, 2-factor-authentication, sms

I do not like having a mobile cellphone and having to carry it around all the time and do 2FA by SMS, but many services I use require it, as does my school. I also lost my phone and cannot afford a new one at the moment. I do have a SIM card with a mobile plan; is there any way I can get the SMS messages on my PC?

OS: Linux Mint
PC: Thinkpad X220
Carrier: Koodo
Location: Canada

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I do have a SIM card with a mobile plan; is there any way I can get the SMS messages on my PC?

You need a device to connect to a mobile network; so, no, you can't without a phone or some other kind of mobile network *user equipment* (UE), and a phone would by far be the cheapest option. (Other options are hard; there's modems, but receiving SMS needs extra daemons, and they're typically more expensive and hard to get to run, and you need to check whether yours will work with your needs, if you're not to risk an investment. There's also embedded wireless modules that are also modems but simply connect via a serial line with TTL levels and take AT commands. If that doesn't tell you what they do, they're not for you.)

Also, you only need a 2G phone; a used Nokia/motorola/Siemens GSM phone runs [CAD 30 to 70 on ebay](https://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_oaa=1&_dcat=9355&_fsrp=1&rt=nc&_from=R40&LH_PrefLoc=1&_stpos=G1H%206J6&_nkw=phone&_sacat=0&Network=Unlocked&LH_BIN=1&_sop=15&_fcid=2&_udhi=50&Brand=Nokia%7CMotorola%7CSiemens). I would, however, ask your classmates whether they have a slightly broken one that they'd lend to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a piece of hardware that can talk to the mobile network, but that could be just an USB 3G dongle cellular modem, for example. Once you connect it to your computer, you could then run [gammu](https://wammu.eu/gammu/) to receive (and eventually send) SMS.

Alternatively you could connect the dongle and install gammu to a computer somewhere, say a raspberry, and access the SMS messages via web from wherever you have a working internet connection, with gammu's REST interface.

A search for "Raspberry Pi powered SMS Gateway" will most likely return provide some tutorials and other software alternatives for Linux.